# WPF: Setting DataGrid FallBackValue to today's date

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

WPF DataGrid having `ItemSource` as `ObservableCollection` with [Date] cell bound to the `DateTime Date` property in each object of the collection.  The `Date` property already defaults to `DateTime.Now` so the value is already in the underlying property:

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

After clicking in the cell, the [Date] value appears and the DatePicker correctly highlights the current date.

But I want the new row in the DataGrid to **automatically** display the current date by default so the user doesn't even have to touch the field when accepting the default, current date.  As seen in the image and XAML, I am successfully using `FallBackValue='N'` for [Cl] and `FallBackValue='$0.00'` for [Amount].  However, I tried `FallbackValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}` for [Date] but it remains empty.

[image: Empty date value in new row]

[image: Property value appears when editing]

```
...
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<DataGrid Visibility="{Binding BankDataGridVisibility}" ItemsSource="{Binding BankTransactions}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,50,10,10" RowHeaderWidth ="0" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date" Width="100" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, FallbackValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=\{0:MM/dd/yyyy\}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    ...
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the FallbackValue for DatePicker binding?

Comment: @Aakanksha: Yes, while it allows for FallbackValue in the DatePicker binding, it doesn't have any noticeable affect.  If I set FallbackValue of the TextBlock binding to a literal value (e.g., FallbackValue='asdf'), it will dutifully display that literal value as I desire.  It just doesn't work if I try to use sys:DateTime.Now.